# What happens when log domain changes

Tags: functions

For example, let's say we have (log is defined base e)
$
\log(\log (n^2))=\log(2\log n)=\log2+\log(\log n)
$
When applying the rules, we clearly see that the domain of n changed.

My question is that does the same thing happens when you are factoring square roots? For example $\sqrt{(8-x)(x-6)}+\sqrt{(x-6)(x+2)}=\sqrt{x-6}\cdot (\sqrt{8-x}+\sqrt{x+2})$
In this example, the domain of x is consistent. I wonder that if it is possible that the domain changes when you are factoring roots. Or maybe even some more award functions. Is this possible? If not, why not?

Comment: How do we see that $\log 2$ is not defined? It is defined.

Comment: $\log_e2=\ln2\approx0.693$.

Comment: Oh, sorry... I made a mistake. let me edit the problem

Comment: I just changed it... I didn't mean to say it. Sorry!

Comment: I just find out there is one in square root too. Consider $\sqrt{(x-6)^2}=\sqrt{x-6}\cdot \sqrt{x-6}$ This is not valid since we need to put absolute value bars around $x-6$ But now, does this case apply to other squares roots functions? I mean the situation when you have something like $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ where $a\neq b$

Comment: Have in mind that it is $\log x^2 =2\log |x|.$

Comment: I just discovered that when you factor $\sqrt{(x-5)(x-6)}=\sqrt{x-5}\sqrt{x-6}$ the domain changed. Can anyone help me generalize these situations? What is going on? Doesn't factoring give the same function?